# Jquery mouse click event not working with certain function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mouseevent, dom-events

I'm not that experienced in front-end but was wondering where the bug is that is making me unable to use the function down below in combination with the element.getBoundingClientRect() function:

```
$(document).on('click','img',function(){
    alert("Click event works!");
});
```

I'm creating an annotation tool for multiple views of my dataset that can be seen below:
[image: annotation tool]

I have been able to make a zoom-in function, which makes it much easier to see where my mouse is over the image I'm trying to label. The problem is when I use this function with a click event, the click event will not work. In the function to get my mouse position:

```
function getCursorPos(e) {
    var a, x = 0, y = 0;
    e = e || window.event;
    a = img.getBoundingClientRect();
    x = e.pageX - a.left;
    y = e.pageY - a.top;
    x = x - window.pageXOffset;
    y = y - window.pageYOffset;
    return {x : x, y : y};
}
```

If I replace `a = img.getBoundingClientRect();` by arbitrary values, the click function will work, but with this line it will not. It would be awesome if someone could tell me why this occurs and what I can do to make both the click event and the getCursorPos() function to work.

[The full code can be found here.](https://www.pastiebin.com/5d9e3e8cef17b)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where does the `img` variable come from?  And are there any console errors?

Comment: img var comes from document.getElementById({id_of_image});. Unfortunaly no console errors, and If I try to debug, the program just skips the break points related to the click event.

Comment: It's hard to follow what you're trying to achieve. Also, the code you linked to seems to be having some errors when I look at the log. Are you trying to attach an event to every image on your page? That's what you're doing with this block of code: ```$(document).on('click','img',function(){
    alert("Click event works!");
});``` Can you clarify what you're trying to achieve? I can't seem to wrap my head around it. What should happen when your image is clicked?

Comment: It will probably have some errors because the files are local and most variables are put in the script with Flask. This click function is still the beginning, but my end goal is to be able to click the image in the location I want it to and a bounding box will be drawn over that location. The click function is working, but only when I comment out `a = img.getBoundingClientRect();`

Comment: I would suggest you print any and all values related to getting the image to console or an alert to confirm it's getting the image correctly. If you're having errors calling a function in relation to an object it honestly might be some strange null error.

Comment: Alternatively, print the values for `a.left` and `a.top` to console just in case `x = e.pageX - a.left;     y = e.pageY - a.top;` are returning negatives or something

Comment: It is getting the image correctly the problem I'm having is that it is not getting the click event, even when I click on the image. This click event is only not working when I uncomment `$a = img.getBoundingClientRect();`, which is a function required to get the lens of my image.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

My click function on the image did not work because of my move lens function which placed a CSS element behind my mouse and in front of my image. By replacing the selector in the click function to the selector of the lens and not the image, my function finally worked. Thank you all for trying to help me.